# How to get all the permutations of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need to create an algorithm that gives all possible variation of an array. For example.

```
getVariations([1,2,3]) ;
```

should return

```
 [
   [1,2,3],
   [1,3,2],
   [2,1,3],
   [2,3,1],
   [3,1,2],
   [3,2,1]
 ]
```

I create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/uf1xot3x/.

Comment: Do you mean permutations?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript

Comment: @Oriol thank you for giving me the right term :)

Comment: smells like homework to me